# InfoPath 2010: Dev Machine Rebuilt, Can't Reapply Certificate

Tags: infopath, certificate

I have an InfoPath 2010 (IP) Full Trust Form with C# code behind. It had been published to Sharepoint 2010 (in 2010!) with a certificate and all was well!

I just had my dev machine rebuilt, and now the form won't open in IP Designer without detaching the certificate because the certificate isn't found where IP is expecting it.

[image]

The original certificate IS in the Current User Cert Store in Personal, Trusted Root and Trusted Publishers folders.

I re-imported the same certificate to the cert store but still not seen by IP?

[image]

[image]

[image]

I need to re-attach the certificate ASAP!
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved:
The solution to this issue was to create a new certificate and apply it to the existing form via InfoPath Designer.
The new certificate appeared in the same MMC Certificate Store as the old one, but was visible to InfoPath.
No clue why the old one wasn't visible.

Thx for listening :)